# why i am getting tise error " 'gps' location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission."

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i don't know why i am getting this error??

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic);
    
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager
            .PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager
            .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        requestLocationPermission();
    }
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);/
    locationIn(location);

    
private void locationIn( Location location) {

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double timezone = 1;
}

private void requestLocationPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission Needed")
                .setMessage("This permission needed to calculate prayers times")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(basicActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(basicActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode==LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE){
        if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //Toast.makeText(this,"Location permission accepted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Location denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is all my manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

when first I got this error I have made some research and its ends to me adding the runtime permission and even that nothing change I still getting this error. what caused this problem?

Comment: You are calling `getLastKnownLocation()` even if you do not have the permission. Your `requestLocationPermission()` is not a blocking call -- it will return a long time before the user grants you permission.

Comment: Thank you that was true